# AngularJS: Repeat after a particular index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using AngularJS and I have a requirement in which I need to repeat an element *after* a particular index. So, let's say my code is:

```
<label ng-repeat="stones in rocks">
    <a href="#">Rock {{$index}}</a>
    <i class="icon-trash"></i>
</label>
```

Now what I wish is that `<i class="icon-trash"></i>` be repeated only *after* index 3. That is from the fourth stone onwards, I wish to see the recycle bin. How do I achieve this?

Comment: ng-show works well, but if you don't want the `<i ...></i>` element in the DOM, use [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch).

Comment: I'm curious if there's a reason to use ng-switch instead of [ng-if](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngIf) (perhaps your comment is dated to an older release).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow) can take an expression:

```
<label ng-repeat="stones in rocks">
    <a href="#">Rock {{$index}}</a>
    <i class="icon-trash" ng-show="$index > 2"></i><!--$index is 0-based-->
</label>
```

As of version [1.1.5](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), you can keep the unwanted elements out of the DOM with

```
<i class="icon-trash" ng-if="$index > 2"></i>
```

Comment: As of version [1.1.5](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), you can keep the unwanted elements out of the DOM with `<i class="icon-trash" ng-if="$index > 2"></i>`

Answer (score 3):

You might simply hide it in first 3 iterations, using ng-show:

```
<label ng-repeat="stones in rocks">
    <a href="#">Rock {{$index}}</a>
    <i class="icon-trash" ng-show="$index>2"></i>
</label>
```